# Which of the following statements is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

My attempt: I take the matrices which have trace $-1$ and determinant $1$.
As I have tried this question many times and I did not get any matrices which satisfy the conditions of option a), option b), or option c), so from my point of view none of the options are correct.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could vastly improve this question by giving it a meaningful title and using correct spelling and capitalization in your text.

Comment: Hint : Use the Caley-Hamilton-theorem

Comment: pliz help me for title ,,i don't know how to use maths jax @mixedmaths

Comment: here A is not the identity matrix this the main problem,,otherwise i can use caley hamilton theorem also @ peter

Comment: If A is a permutation matrix of order $3$, then it satisfies the conditions of (c), but not the conclusion.

Comment: Counterexample for $a)$ : $$\pmatrix {0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0}$$

Comment: thanks peter for opt A) @ peter

Comment: Note that there is a tempting but incorrect approach here. This is to factor these expressions and then conclude that one of the factors is zero. Factoring these expressions like polynomials is valid, because $A$ and $I$ commute. But there is no zero-product property for matrices. For example, we can say $A^3 - I = (A - I)(A^2 + A + I)$, but we cannot conclude that either $A-I$ or $A^2 + A + I$ is zero from this, since nonzero matrices can multiply to zero. Of course, you could apply a determinant and conclude that either $\det(A-I)$ or $\det(A^2 + A + I)$ is zero, which could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some matrices to think about.

$A = \pmatrix {1\\&1\\&&-1}$

$A = \pmatrix {\cos \frac {2\pi}{3}& \sin \frac {2\pi}{3}\\-\sin \frac {2\pi}{3}&\cos \frac {2\pi}{3}}$

$A = \pmatrix {1&&\\&\cos \frac {2\pi}{3}& \sin \frac {2\pi}{3}\\&-\sin \frac {2\pi}{3}&\cos \frac {2\pi}{3}}$

In all of the scenarios

$A^n = I$ says something about the eigenvalues of $A$

Then there is a further clause that restricts what those eigenvalues may be.

And finally, do all matrices that meet the previous 2 constraints meet the 3rd constraint.

Update.

$A = \pmatrix {-\frac 12& \frac {\sqrt 3}{2}\\-\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}&-\frac 12}$

$A^2 = \pmatrix {-\frac 12& -\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}\\\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}&-\frac 12}$

$A^2+A+I = 0$

Comment: let me check whethear this matrix satisfied or not @ Doug M

Comment: ya  ,,i have checked all ur matrices that mean  none of the of option is correct ,,,Am i right? @ doug M

Comment: No, the first matrix is a counterexample that proves a) is false.  It meets the criteria, but not the conclusion.  Same thing for the 3rd matrix and c).  The second matrix meets the criteria and the conclusion of b), but that is not enough for a proof.  But these examples should give you enough to work with to prove b)

Comment: can u liitle bit elaborate why option b is coorect,,?@  Doug M,,,,,,as i have check ur  given matrix for optiob B) that is A^2 + A +I is not equal to zero..

Comment: Sure it does... I have put in an update.

Comment: thank u so much @ Doug M ....im getting now ,im vote up u now